Reactの複雑なフォームの状態を効率的に管理する方法は？
現在、Reactを使用して複雑なフォームを構築しています。このフォームには、ドロップダウンやファイルアップロード、入力バリデーションなど、複数のフィールドが含まれています。
現在の実装では、以下のようにuseStateを使って各フィールドの状態を個別に管理しています：

const [fatherCatId, setFatherCatId] = useState<string>('');
    const [motherCatId, setMotherCatId] = useState<string>('');
    const [breedId, setBreedId] = useState<string>('');
    const [colorId, setColorId] = useState<string>('');
    const [sex, setSex] = useState<string>('');
    const [birthDate, setBirthDate] = useState<Dayjs | null>(null);
    const [description, setDescription] = useState<string>('');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState<number | ''>('');
    const [tranState, setTranState] = useState<string>('');
    const [uploadedImages, setUploadedImages] = useState<File[]>([]);
    const [uploadedVideo, setUploadedVideo] = useState<FileList | null>(null);
    const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState<BreedsType[]>([]);
    const [colors, setColors] = useState<ColorsType[]>([]);
    const [maleCats, setMaleCats] = useState<ParentCatsType[]>([]);
    const [femaleCats, setFemaleCats] = useState<ParentCatsType[]>([]);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
        fatherCatId: false,
        motherCatId: false,
        breedId: false,
        colorId: false,
        sex: false,
        birthDate: false,
        description: false,
        price: false,
        tranState: false,
    });


しかし、フィールドの数が増えるにつれて、コードが管理しにくくなってきました。このような場合、状態管理を効率化するための良い方法が知りたいです。
例えば、以下のような方法を検討しています：
・各フィールドを一つのオブジェクトで管理する方法
・react-hook-formのようなライブラリを使う方法
複雑なフォームを扱う際におすすめのアプローチがあれば教えてください。可能であれば、コード例もいただけると助かります！
